# Detecting https in htaccess - all possibilites

Tags: .htaccess, http, https

```
RewriteRule .* - [E=protocol:http]

RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} ^on$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{ENV:REQUEST_SCHEME} ^https$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ^on$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_SCHEME} ^https$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} ^https$ [NC]
    RewriteRule .* - [E=protocol:https]
```

How it is possible that code above doesn't work? This code checking literally in every possible way whether it's http or https to store it to var.

But at the end `protocol` var has always `http` value. Doesn't matter if you type `http://example.com` or `https://example.com`

Comment: This works for me as it is.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that is working for me is:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$
```

So weird that the most popular ways don't work.